Why are my Docker containers and volumes automatically deleted on Ubuntu VPS hosted by Hostinger?
I am facing an issue with Docker Compose on my VPS hosted by Hostinger, running Ubuntu. Whenever I use Docker Compose to create and start my containers, everything works fine initially. However, after a few hours, the volumes and database data are automatically deleted, although the containers themselves remain running.
Questions:
What could be causing the automatic deletion of Docker volumes and database data after a few hours?
Are there any Hostinger-specific settings or configurations that might lead to this behavior?
How can I prevent Docker from automatically deleting volumes and losing database data?
Thank you!
